# After jquery click function hover not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am recently started to learning jQuery and now I am stuck with this problem,
everything working as expected but after the click function execute jquery hover function is not working...

```js
$(function(){
    $("div.star").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("star-hover");
    });

    $("div.star").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("star-hover");
    );
});

$(function(){
    $("div.star").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("star-chosen");
    });
});
```

```css
.star {
     height: 2em;
     width: 2em;
     border: .1em solid black;
     border-radius: 1.1em;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0;
     padding: .1em;
}

.star-hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

.star-chosen {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the element has both classes `star-hover` and `star-chosen`, it's really the problem as to which `background-color` to apply.

Why don't just use css `:hover`:

```
.star {
   height: 2em;
   width: 2em;
   border: .1em solid black;
   border-radius: 1.1em;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0;
   padding: .1em;
  }

 .star:hover  {
   background-color: blue;
  }

  .star-chosen {
   background-color: red;
  }
```

Your js:

```
$(function(){
  $("div.star").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("star-chosen");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yyqwkaqp/

If you're looking for a jQuery approach, you have to add `!important` to `star-hover`:

```
.star-hover {
   background-color: blue !important;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d8wmhmrp/

But I would prefer the `:hover` solution

Comment: Thanks @Khanh TO css :hover is fine but I am looking the jQuery way :)

Comment: @Joy07: then you have to add `!important`

Answer (score 0):

write in CSS .star-hover after .star-chosen it help you

why you add class if hover? it can make using CSS
see this solution:

```js
$("div.star").click(function () {
  $(this).addClass("star-chosen");
});
```

```css
.star {
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    border: .1em solid black;
    border-radius: 1.1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .1em;
}
.star-chosen {
    background-color: red;
}
.star:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
</div>
```